# Google Earth does not work on KML Files with <TimeSpan> and YYYY-MM-DD but working with YYYY-MM?

Tags: google-earth

I have a KML File with a Folder and 5 overlapping Polygons which each of them has a `<Timespan>` Element with `<Begin>` and `<end>` like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Pflanzungen.kml</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Style id="Feld0004">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>0.4</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/star.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <color>9900ffff</color>
        <scale>1</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff00ffff</color>
            <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>6600ffff</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="Feld0003">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>0.4</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/star.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <color>9900ffff</color>
        <scale>1</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
            <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>660000ff</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="Feld0001">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>0.4</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/star.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <color>9900ffff</color>
        <scale>1</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff10ff10</color>
            <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>6610ff10</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="Feld0000">
    </Style>
    <Style id="Feld0002">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>0.4</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/star.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <color>9900ffff</color>
        <scale>1</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ffff8418</color>
            <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>66ff8418</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="Feld0005">
      <IconStyle>
        <scale>0.4</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/star.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <color>9900ffff</color>
        <scale>1</scale>
      </LabelStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff8080ff</color>
            <width>2</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>668080ff</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
        <name>^Alle</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <styleUrl>#Feld0000</styleUrl>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Test1 2016/19</name>
            <TimeSpan>
        <begin>2016-11-2</begin>
        <end>2019-11-1</end>
            </TimeSpan>
            <styleUrl>#Feld0001</styleUrl>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            -77.05860079207011,38.86999379928544,0 -77.05554907665893,38.86880793040165,0 -77.05310313779386,38.87066286135065,0 -77.05464010084096,38.87306915897465,0 -77.05803254214114,38.87281900611599,0 -77.05860079207011,38.86999379928544,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Test2 2019/20</name>
            <TimeSpan>
        <begin>2019-11-2</begin>
        <end>2020-11-1</end>
            </TimeSpan>
            <styleUrl>#Feld0002</styleUrl>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            -77.05860079207011,38.86999379928544,0 -77.05554907665893,38.86880793040165,0 -77.05310313779386,38.87066286135065,0 -77.05464010084096,38.87306915897465,0 -77.05803254214114,38.87281900611599,0 -77.05860079207011,38.86999379928544,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Test3 2020/21</name>
            <TimeSpan>
         <begin>2020-11-2</begin>
        <end>2021-11-1</end>
            </TimeSpan>
            <styleUrl>#Feld0003</styleUrl>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            -77.05860079207011,38.86999379928544,0 -77.05554907665893,38.86880793040165,0 -77.05310313779386,38.87066286135065,0 -77.05464010084096,38.87306915897465,0 -77.05803254214114,38.87281900611599,0 -77.05860079207011,38.86999379928544,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Test4 2021/22</name>
            <TimeSpan>
        <begin>2021-11-2</begin>
        <end>2022-11-1</end>
      </TimeSpan>
            <styleUrl>#Feld0004</styleUrl>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            -77.05860079207011,38.86999379928544,0 -77.05554907665893,38.86880793040165,0 -77.05310313779386,38.87066286135065,0 -77.05464010084096,38.87306915897465,0 -77.05803254214114,38.87281900611599,0 -77.05860079207011,38.86999379928544,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Test5 2022/23</name>
            <TimeSpan>
         <begin>2022-11-2</begin>
        <end>2023-11-1</end>
            </TimeSpan>
            <styleUrl>#Feld0005</styleUrl>
            <Polygon>
                <outerBoundaryIs>
                    <LinearRing>
                        <coordinates>
                            -77.05860079207011,38.86999379928544,0 -77.05554907665893,38.86880793040165,0 -77.05310313779386,38.87066286135065,0 -77.05464010084096,38.87306915897465,0 -77.05803254214114,38.87281900611599,0 -77.05860079207011,38.86999379928544,0 
                        </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
                </outerBoundaryIs>
            </Polygon>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Loading this File in Google Earth Pro 7.3.2.5491 (64-bit) for windows 10 does not even show the timeslider. Saving the same File to disk shows, that inside the `<TimeSpan>` elements is missing each of the `<begin>` and `<end>` elements (in all 5 placemarks). The same thing with a bigger file has other errors, sometimes only missing `<begin>` and at other placemarks only missing the `<end>`.

If I change in the same file all the `<begin>` and `<end>` elements to the form yyyy-mm simply by deleting the "-dd" part. After doing so, the Timeslider works fine as expected. I do not have any idea what could be wrong with the yyyy-mm-dd version.

There has not been reported any error from google earth while loading the file, and I have restarted earth pro with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date format is not quite right.  Try making the day numbers 2-digits each, for example `2016-11-2` becomes `2016-11-02` (added a zero).

KML dateTime is based on XML Schema time and should be expressed as: 
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:sszzzzzz
... where T is the separator between the date and the time, and the time zone is either Z (for UTC) or zzzzzz, which represents ±hh:mm in relation to UTC. And as you know, it can be expressed as a date only (without the time parts).

More details in the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/time#how-to-specify-time
and here: 
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#timestamp